# Creating list from a string, splitting at comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I'm currently working on a project, which inputs from a file, the following information:

```
10015, John, Smith, 2, 3.01
10208, Patrick, Green, 1, 3.95
10334, Jane, Roberts, 4, 3.81
```

What I need to do is split this information, store each value separately, then print it out to the screen or file based on what the user needs.

The function which should split and then assign information is this:

```
def fetchRecord( self ):
    #Read the first line of the record.
    line = self._inputFile.readline()
    line = input.split( ', ' )
    if line == "":
        return None

    #If there is another record, create a storage object and fill it
    student = StudentRecord()
    student.idNum = int( line[0] ) 
    student.firstName = line[1]
    student.lastName = line[2]
    student.classCode = int( line[3] )
    student.gpa = float( line[4] )
    return student
```

The error I'm currently getting is the following:

```
builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10015, John, Smith, 2, 3.01\n'
```

The entire code I'm calling is:

```
class StudentFileReader:
#Create new student reader instance.
def __init__( self, inputSrc ):
    self._inputSrc = inputSrc
    self._inputFile = None

#Open a connection to the input file.
def open( self ):
    self._inputFile = open( self._inputSrc, "r" )

#Close the connection to the input file.
def close( self ):
    self._inputFile.close()
    self._inputFile = None

#Extract all student records and store them in a list.
def fetchAll( self ):
    theRecords = list()
    student = self.fetchRecord()
    while student != None:
        theRecords.append( student )
        student = self.fetchRecord()
    return theRecords

#Extract the next stuent record from the file.
def fetchRecord( self ):
    #Read the first line of the record.
    line = self._inputFile.readline()
    print ( line )
    line = line.split( ',' )
    print ( line )
    if line == "":
        return None

    #If there is another record, create a storage object and fill it
    student = StudentRecord()
    student.idNum = int( line[0] ) 
    student.firstName = line[1]
    student.lastName = line[2]
    student.classCode = int( line[3] )
    student.gpa = float( line[4] )
    return student


class StudentScreenWriter:
    #Prints the student report to screen.
    def printReport( theList ):
         #The class names associated with the class codes.
         classNames = ( None, "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior" )

        #Print the header.
        print( "LIST OF STUDNETS".center(50) )
        print( "" )
        print( "%-5s %-25s %-10s %-4s" % ('ID', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'GPA' ) )
        print( "%5s %25s %10s %4s" % ('-' * 5, '-' * 25, '-' * 10, '-' * 4) )

        #Print the body.
        for record in theList:
            print( "%5d %-25s %-10s %4.2f" % (record.idNum, record.lastName + ", " + record.firstName, classNames[record.classCode], record.gpa) )

        #Add a footer.
        print( "-" * 50 )
        print( "Number of students:", len(theList) )

class StudentFileWriter:
    #Prints the student report to file.
    def printReport( theList, out ):
        for record in theList
            record.idNum = str(record.idNum)
            record.lastName = str(record.lastName)
            record.firstName = str(record.firstName)
            record.classCode = str(record.classCode)
            record.gpa = str(record.gpa)

            out.write( record.idNum + ", " + record.lastName + ", " + record.firstName + ", " + record.classCode + ", " + record.gpa )
        out.write( "\n" )


class StudentRecord:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.idNum = None
        self.firstName = None
        self.lastName = None
        self.classCode = None
        self.gpa = None
```

Comment: it should be line.split( ', ' )

Comment: I don't think you should have a space after the comma. CSV files are strictly separated by a single character. The reason I am saying this is that splitting the line up will be safer, especially for missing data. i.e. `10015,John,Smith,,3.01`

Answer (score 4):

not the answer you are looking for but you should consider

```
class StudentRecord:
     def __init__(self,idNum=-1,firstName="unknown",lastName="Unknown",classCode=-1,gpa=-1):
         self.idNum = idNum
         self.firstName = firstName
         self.lastName = lastName
         self.classCode = classCode
         self.gpa = gpa
     #... The rest of your class
```

with csv module

```
import csv
with open("some.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for student_details in reader:
        student = StudentRecord(*student_details)
```

without csv module

```
with open("some.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        student_details = line.split(",")
        student = StudentRecord(*student_details)
```

testing with your data

```
class StudentRecord:
    def __init__(self,idNum=-1,firstName="unknown",lastName="Unknown",classCode=-1,gpa=-1):
        self.idNum = idNum
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.classCode = classCode
        self.gpa = gpa
    def  __str__(self):
        return "#%s:%s, %s | %s = %s"%(
            self.idNum,self.lastName,self.firstName,
            self.classCode,self.gpa
            )
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Student Record (%s %s)>"%(
            self.firstName,self.lastName
            )

with open("txt_data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        student_data = line.strip().split(", ")
        student = StudentRecord(*student_data)
        print "Student:",student
```

outputs:

```
Student: #10015:Smith, John | 2 = 3.01
Student: #10208:Green, Patrick | 1 = 3.95
Student: #10334:Roberts, Jane | 4 = 3.81
```

Comment: In case you are rewriting and advising a better solution, please advised to use `csv` module to parse a csv file

Comment: edited  ... i think thats how you do it with csv reader :P ... its been a while

Comment: The csv.reader module has always seemed like a classic case of overkill to me; for an example as simple as this, your code changes from one blindingly obvious line of code (line.split(',')) to a method call that you have to try to remember the syntax for

Comment: there :P now everyones happy

Comment: @sapi I personally think the cost of learning the syntax is far outweighed by the extra features it has built-in. For instance, if the OP were using a European numbering scheme (with `3,85` instead of `3.85`) the splits wouldn't work as expected (nor would they in fields with commas inside of them).

Comment: Thanks for all this help guys, but we're not allowed to use the `csv` module. We have to use the code and tools given above.

Comment: thats the bottom solution ... I think your input file isnt quite how you describe it

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried your `csv` fix, and it still didn't work. It gave me the same error.

Comment: `10015, John, Smith, 2, 3.01`
`10208, Patrick, Green, 1, 3.95`
`10334, Jane, Roberts, 4, 3.81`

Each segment is on a new line.

Comment: The input file is just a file called `"students.txt"` which only includes the first three lines at the beginning of the top question.

Comment: edited to show what happens when i run it against a file I cut and pasted your example input into

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22557/discussion-between-keyfer-mathewson-and-joran-beasley)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line

```
 line = input.split( ', ' )
```

to

```
line = line.split( ',' )
```

and move it after

```
if line == "":
    return None
```

`input` is undefined in the current context.

Comment: @KeyferMathewson: What happened after the fix?

Comment: try printing the line before you split it .. and after ... and put your results in the original question

Comment: @JoranBeasley For some reason it's not even printing to the shell. I'll post the entire code above.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider this for spliting the  data (used your data)

```
>>> for line in f:  
        li1 = []  
        for part in line.split(','):  
                part = part.strip()  
                li1.append(part)  
        li2.append(li1)  

>>> for i in li2:
        print i
['10015', 'John', 'Smith', '2', '3.01']  
['10208', 'Patrick', 'Green', '1', '3.95']  
['10334', 'Jane', 'Roberts', '4', '3.81']
```

`li1`and`li2`are lists. And `f` is the input file in which each line has a record/data.

You will now have the list. You can use the same method(s) to get and process the name,class code,gpa etc.